# How can <footer>/<header>/<div>'s with 100% width, yet discrepancies in mobile browsers, be combatted?

Tags: css, mobile, width, mobile-safari, viewport

After migrating a website to responsive html5 using media queries, I find that I still can't get the mobile iOS 7 safari browser to display the footer/main/header sections at the same width, despite their css being set to display:block and width:100%.
Examples:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv3r1.jpg

http://dev.shermanbrothers.com (username: devreview password: De3e3vfr4 ) [html5 update to site]

And a similar problem occurs even on an older version of the site:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4nL6.jpg

http://shermanbrothers.com [OLD version of the site with table-based layout, still has similar issues]

Now, I have some guesses as to -why- this is happening on mobile and not on the narrow windows of a desktop browser:

- Some block level elements like the main/between-header-and-footer one have too much content to even shrink down to that 100%
- Or perhaps using display:table on the middle section is allowing it to blow up larger than the other block & 100% width elements.

But I don't know what techniques to use to combat the problem. 
- I can't even inspect the code via mobile to determine the reasons for the differences.
- setting a css max-width to images (eg max-width:100% ) within their container is not better.

So how can mobile-specific bugs, and mobile width/layout issues especially, be debugged & dealt with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tables are a huge headache for diagnosing this problem since there is so much markup to look through.  However, the tables are not the reason why your layout is breaking (at least not with the markup I saw when I came across this question).  Your problem is that you have so many fixed widths on images, text and table columns.

To fix this, you will have to set-up breakpoints in your media queries.  Something like this for the images:

```
@media (min-width: Whatever is the smallest screen size the image will not break your layout) and (max-width: 1 pixel below the previous size where the image was so wide it broke your layout) {
    .header-image {
        width: whatever is the widest width that keeps it from breaking your layout; // This will change with smaller queries
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

And something like this for your fonts:

```
@media (min-width: Whatever is the smallest size the font will not break your layout) and (max-width: 1 pixel below the previous size where the font was so wide it broke your layout) {
    .navbar-font {
        font-size: whatever is the biggest font size that keeps the font from breaking your layout;

    }
}
```

Alternatively for your fonts, you could tell them to wrap as the screen gets smaller, but then you would have to factor in their height as they wrapped:

```
.navbar-font {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Do something similar with the above to allow the width of your table columns to resize properly as well.

Also, follow @TylerEich 's suggestion and configure your viewports.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/best-practices.html

Finally, check out [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/mobile-browser-emulator) for mobile browser testing.

This may not fix all of your layout issues, but it fixed the biggest ones I found.  Table-based layouts are a pain to work with.  Good luck :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, the links in the original post were ordered a little weird, the live site is a table-based layout, the new dev site is html5.  Yet the problems with not being able to acheive 100% width persist.  I do use BrowserStack!  But being able to see that it's broken doesn't help  me in figuring out why in this case, as the css is explicit that the footer should be 100% width, the header should be 100% width, etc.  But I will consider your take-font-into-consideration suggestion.

Comment: I think this answer is probably closest to getting me where I want to go, so I'm giving you the bounty (though for now I still don't have a solution).

Answer (score 2):

## font-size

the top element of the footer columns (`footer-flex`) has a `font-size: 10px`. And the child element (`.footer-block`) has a `font-size: 2em`. This means the `.footer-block` elements have `font-size: 20px`. (10px(top element font-size) * 2em) = 20px. This causes big texts in your footer.

## display

You're using `float` to align elements side by side which is a very bad practice. If you'd like to align elements properly you should select `display: table-cell` or `display: inline-block`. The difference is `table-cell` is just like `<td>` tag. Which means all the consecutive elements has the same `height`.

Because `table-cell` acts just like `td` tag the `table-cell` cannot have `margin`s. If you'd like to have `margin`s for your `table-cell` you need to provide a top element which is `display: table` with a style `border-spacing`. An example which is very proper for your case: http://jsfiddle.net/R3zDu/

As you can see there is no `clear: both` or `float: blah` definitions and clear css definition.

This doesn't mean "don't use `float` anymore". `float`'s main purpose is to align the images in the texts/paragraphs.

1. clear all the `float` and `clear: both` styles.
2. apply `table-cell` method.

## testing

I don't think there is a software that renders the page just like a mobile phone. On the other hand, if you have problems in iOS you can take a look at Safari browser in your PC or Mac which acts like iOS Safari in most cases (at least in your case).

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, this shrinkage problem doesn't occur on the iPad safari browser, which makes it hard to test for.  I'll investigate the display:inline-block/display:table-cell suggestions, I thought floating in the interior of the body wouldn't really be a problem, but I'll check out how that plays into the mobile layout.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a mobile-friendly `<meta>` tag. Example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

---

### Quote from the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag):

A typical mobile-optimized site contains something like the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

The `width` property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like `width=600` or to the special value `device-width` value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%. (There are corresponding `height` and `device-height` values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size or position based on the viewport height.)

The `initial-scale` property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. The `maximum-scale`, `minimum-scale`, and `user-scalable` properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> is already present in the html.  I'll see if user-scalable=no makes a difference.

Comment: Currently shermanbrothers.com has: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`  and dev.shermanbrothers.com has: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`  But neither settings appear to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#head{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

  #content_head{
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
  }

#body{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

  #content_body{
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
  }

#footer{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

  #content_footer{
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
```

Comment: Use this to use 100% of html area.

Comment: the div's content_ are in center of div father

Comment: ...this is not very helpful without the actual html, I frankly don't see how using floats inside the contents of display table elements is going to be an improvement...

Comment: This code centralizy the div #content_divfather in #divfather, you use to use 100% of screen in all resolutions

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of code that needs to be redone.

Instead of being this painful, I highly recommend you to look into a framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). They both provide good template example to help you get started. Their media queries also work like a charm and they will help you cut lots of development time and some headache.

Comment: Twitter-bootstrapping the site is going to be a later step, I had to update the underlying html before it would even be an option.  Anyway, bootstrap isn't going to prevent me from encountering the same type of problem again, so I have to figure out some way to counteract it regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, and don't want to do a complete overhaul, I would suggest you set:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=500px" />
```

And try fixing the things that float out of your 500px width (like the navigation).

This way, you don't have to do much work. The site is more or less a bit normal visible on a mobile. I studied your code a little, but it's a lot of working if you want to do it proper.

500px is somewhat ok for a mobile device, but you can tweak it to what you like, it isn't as nice as device-width but gives you a fair compromis between your pile of work to do and the general user experience. As long as you allow zooming (user scaling).

One other trick I suggest is to make the font a tiny bit bigger on mobile on some parts, like your brand nav. And form elements always minimal 16px so you don't get zooming on an iPhone when you focus a field.

```
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
    .brand-name-td{
        font-size:1em;
    }
    input[type="text"],select,textarea{
        font-size:16px;
    }
}
```

Further, what's handy and improves the UX, there are some parts you just want to hide on a phone, use this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
    .hide-mobile{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

And just when you have some element you want to hide, add the class (divide by a space if you have more classes)

```
 <td class="right-side-nav-container hide-mobile">...</td>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

use diplay block and width to 100%,  remove also float and max-width, min-width property.

Also you can simulate a mobile just by using a browser since you already have the viewport metadata. Just resize the width of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I picked up this handy little fix while browsing some random sites in firebug, it looks like what you're describing, why not give it a go and see if it works :P

```
    $(function(){
    // IPad/IPhone
    var viewportmeta = document.querySelector && document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]'),
    ua = navigator.userAgent,

    gestureStart = function () {
        viewportmeta.content = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6";
    },

    scaleFix = function () {
        if (viewportmeta && /iPhone|iPad/.test(ua) && !/Opera Mini/.test(ua)) {
        viewportmeta.content = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0";
        document.addEventListener("gesturestart", gestureStart, false);
        }
    };
    scaleFix();
    });
```